# JQuery drag, drop and save via cookie - how to?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, cookies

Sorry to be back folks, but you guys & girls seem to know much more about this than I do ...
anyhow, here is my question/problem

I want to use drag, drop, sort (the interface plugin does me even though I have read it's out of date? but have looked at UI and to be honest is not clear and to me appears heavier than interface?)

Anyhow, how do I set a cookie to save positions from this:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $('a.closeEl').bind('click', toggleContent);
    $('div.groupWrapper').Sortable(
        {
            accept: 'groupItem',
            helperclass: 'sortHelper',
            activeclass : 'sortableactive',
            hoverclass : 'sortablehover',
            handle: 'div.itemHeader',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            onChange : function(ser)
            {
            },
            onStart : function()
            {
                $.iAutoscroller.start(this, document.getElementsByTagName('body'));
            },
            onStop : function()
            {
                $.iAutoscroller.stop();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

);

```
var toggleContent = function(e)
{
    var targetContent = $('div.itemContent', this.parentNode.parentNode);
    if (targetContent.css('display') == 'none') {
        targetContent.slideDown(300);
        $(this).html('[-]');
    } else {
        targetContent.slideUp(300);
        $(this).html('[+]');
    }
    return false;
};

var ser = function (s) {
    serial = $.SortSerialize(s);
    alert(serial.hash);
};
```

which is the "standard" interface demo, PLUS

How do I then get to read that cookie so that when I next visit the page the order is as I set it in the cookie?

Hopefully from that I can work out the rest .......?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out: [Remembering a jQuery draggable tool palette position between page refreshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328249/remembering-a-jquery-draggable-tool-palette-position-between-page-refreshes)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fully working code which I am using for my admin panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/Frenki/7dr6a/2/

Add class="itemDrag" to div that you want to drag, you can have as many divs inside as you want. and keep #drop-esquarda id as it is, and it will work for you. Also every new div you add need to have class="itemDrag" + some unique id and thats all, you can have as many as you like, dont forget to include jquery cookie plugin, jquery UI and ofcoruse jquery itself